MAUI iOS Release - Trimming in Release is too aggressive, is there a workaround?
Description
I'm facing a problem that I'm trying to resolve. My MAUI Blazor Hybrid app implements Blazor wrapper for a JavaScript library Leaflet for interactive maps in Blazor. Everything works well, map is properly drawed for Windows (Debug/Release) and for Android (Debug/ Release).
Debug mode on iOS platform works normally. Release mode on iOS doens't work properly and map is not drawed. On Android it works, because it is possible to turn trimming off and publish without it, but it is not allowed on iOS.
Is there a workaround or can someone help? I created public repo, the problem can be demostrated there.
Steps to Reproduce
Switch to Release.
Start without debugging on physical devices. Expect same behaviour on iOS simulators.
Link to public reproduction project repository
https://github.com/semdevel/MapApp
Fully functional MAUI iOS Release like Debug for uploading my app on AppStore.

You can disable trim by adding <IsTrimmable>false</IsTrimmable> to the libraries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/prepare-libraries-for-trimming?pivots=dotnet-8-0#enable-project-specific-trimming

This: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/linking?view=net-maui-8.0

I was testing both variants, I turned off whatever was possible according to the guidances but the problem with Release mode on iOS platform still persist... :(
Can someone test it alone using my as simplest as possible demo app for demostration? Here is the link: https://github.com/semdevel/MapApp

@PetrSemrad what is your current linker configuration. What does it say bellow "Release and .NET-ios"?

@H.A.H. Here is my current configuration for Release and .NET-ios:
`
false


False
None
False
`
@PetrSemrad Right click on your project file, select Properties, navigate to IOS, then navigate to BUILD and then check the options for linking, optimizing, stripping symbols etc.

Another interesting moment, how are you provisioning this application?

So, I tested these configurations:
`
false


false
`
and
`
false


false
Full
`
Both configurations have same problem. My provisioning profile looks like:
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">    <ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>    <CodesignKey>Apple Development: Created via API (ID)</CodesignKey>    <CodesignProvision>VS: WildCard Development</CodesignProvision>  </PropertyGroup>

Does the same problem occur when running the program in release mode on iOS physical machine? Do you encounter any error messages?

I'm testing it only on physical devices - Iphone 15 Pro and an old Iphone 6. Same problems. I also tried to release app and then tested it using Apple TestFlight. Same problems there too. So, Release mode has to be fixed properly...

You can follow the issue on github: iOS Trimming in Release.

That issue was created by myself. It is still without any constructive feedback.

I managed to resolve the issue. Turns out, the problem was in the code, not with trimming optimization. I have found it and fixed it.
